string remove pattern with special character in R
I have an object in R called text :
text = c(" - John - Loves Helen - Day 4")  


I want to remove the starting space the "-" and the space (i.e) all the special characters before the first word.
ideally I want to the result to be :
John - Loves Helen - Day 4

please take into account that in my real data set the column with text might contain different starting word (i.e different from John).
How can I do that in R ?

substring(text, 2)

This is a very basic question answered several times in slightly different questions on SO. You simply want to remove the first occurence of a special character and any length of additionally leading white space or similar. Just research it with minimal effort. There are plenty of possibilities and helpful shortscuts: everything until first word boundary. Or, even better, learn some helpful basics of regex.

To remove everything before the first "word character" (letter or number) sub("^\\W*", "", text)

@GregorThomas can you please write it as an answer ?

This should work:
text = c(" - John - Loves Helen - Day 4") 

text.split <- unlist(strsplit(text,split = " "))

text.split <- text.split[-c(1,2)]

text.split <- paste(text.split,collapse = " ")

print(text.split)

"John - Loves Helen - Day 4"

This also works and is neater:
text <- sub("^\\W*","",text)

print(text)

"John - Loves Helen - Day 4"

Hope it helps!

Slightly better form would be sub rather than gsub since you're only making 1 replacement per item.

Good observation!
